# Ubuntu 21.10 won't detect microphone on headset

Tags: microphone, mac, settings, 21.10, headset

I am attempting to connect the headset's microphone to my computer; however, the mic is not showing up in the settings. I'd show a picture, but it's not letting me take a screenshot of the window. I found an article online that said to open the settings and then plug in the headset, but that didn't do a thing. I'm curious if the mic might just be for decoration. I am trying to film myself playing Minecraft, but my computer's built-in mic has a bunch of background noise. I don't know why the mic isn't being detected by the system.

System information: I am running Ubuntu 21.10 on a mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro (MacBookPro9,2). I have a Cyber Acoustics AC-5002 headset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an Ubuntu problem or your headset problem.

[image: TRRS]

There're several different 3.5 mm audio cable Jacks.
Your headset is an OMTP (Open Mobile Terminal Protocol).
Apple uses a CTIA (Cellular Telephone Industry Association).
Frankly, OMTP is a Chinese/Korean protocol and CTIA is an American standard.

Solution #1:
You can find a converter like Stereo Audio CTIA OMTP Connector Adapter. Approx. $5 on Amazon.

Solution #2:
Open up either laptop or your headset circuit and rewire these two terminals.